# ** is new power operator instead of power() in php

Tags: php, operators, new-operator, php-5.6

How to use new version of Power operator instead of `pow()` in new version of php (5.6)?
Like:

```
echo pow(2,3);
```

Why output of this line is 512 not 64?

```
2 ** 3 ** 2;
```

Comment: Please, read [wiki RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pow-operator) - there are more than enough samples there.

Comment: Is it really so surprising how a binary operator works? Usually it's `a op b`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a sample ** operator in php 5.6 +

```
$i = 6;

$i **=2; //output 36

$out = $i ** 3 //output 46656

echo 2 ** 3 ** 2; // 512 (not 64) because this line evaluated right to left  => 2 ** (3 ** 2)
echo -3 ** 2; // -9 (not 9)
echo 1 - 3 ** 2; // -8
echo ~3 ** 2; // -10 (not 16)
```

`**` is better than `pow(,)` .
When you try to write a math algorithm. `**` is a Powerful Operator.
there's no functional difference between it and pow.
[power operator refrence](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pow-operator)

Comment: Exactly how is it "better"? Other than being a few less characters, there's no functional difference between it and pow. It's like saying "tool A is better than tool B, because tool A is **PINK**"

Comment: @Marc It may be better depending on the purpose it is used for.  For example, if you were to take user input for an equation solver, and wanted to use exec, you could simply replace `^` with `**` instead of needing to make sure to place that `)` of `pow()` in the right place.

Comment: @MarcB - Better for performance, no overhead of a function call but explicitly handled in exactly the same way as any other arithmetic operator

Comment: @Anonymous - simply replacing `^` with `**` and then what? Please not `eval()`.... otherwise, if you're using a proper formula parser then there's no difference between `^` and `**`

Comment: @Mark Obviously not just using eval.  It's not like I'm setting the basis for such a program.  I'm just providing an example.

Comment: Being the author of `**` I can tell you that it's different from `pow()` in the sense that it transparently supports GMP (if compiled); and it can be used wherever a constant expression is expected, such as a default value or class constant.

Comment: @Ja͢ck, but isn't pow() function implementation replaced by pow_function() call(and supports gmp too) in the same PR?

Comment: @vp_arth tbf, i have not tried that ... you might be right, actually :)

Comment: Note that the output of the third line in the sample code should read `$out = $i ** 3 //output 46656`, not 216, since `$i **= 2` _assigns_ 36 to `$i`, thus `$out = 36 ** 3`. :)

Comment: Why is echo 2 ** 3 ** 2; // 512 but not 64 ?

Comment: @jirigracik logic :)

Comment: Just clarifying (for anyone other future readers)... that `2 ** 3 ** 2` is evaluated as `2 ** (3 ** 2)` which is 512 whereas `(2 ** 3) ** 2` is 64, presumably because exponents are right-associative (they get evaluated right to left) :)