# What is ** Exponentiation operator in php?

Tags: php, math

Can anyone tell what does **`**`** **exponentiation** operator do in php ?

Examples will be more useful.

Thanks

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803213/is-new-power-operator-instead-of-power-in-php

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pow-operator           view this

Comment: Write some code using this operator, it will become clear what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `exponentiation` operator.

**Functionality** :

It gives Result of raising one variable to the other varibale's power 
So if we want nth power of any number for that this operator is used

Example :

```
$x = 5;
$y = 3;
$z = $x ** $y; //<----- raising 3 power of 5 i.e we can say 5 raise to 3 in simple language . $x = base and $y= It is `exponentiation` operator.
echo $z; //results 125
```

Comment: You mean 10 ** 29 = (base = 10 & exponent = 29) ?

Comment: Yes. You got it :)